# NSArray too long?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Im not really sure what cause this problem, but my theory is that Xcode is processing the array too long and the tableview is calling the array before it even manage to process all the strings. Because, when i remove half of the strings it will work and I will get no error message. Is there any way to fix this?

```
Datarray2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"United States Dollar",@"Euro",@"Japanese yen",@"Bulgarian lev",@"Czech koruna",@"Danish krone",@"British pound",@"Hungarian forint"@"Lithuanian litas",@"Polish złoty",@"Romanian leu",@"Swedish krona",@"Swiss franc",@"Norwegian krone",@"Croatian kuna",@"Russian ruble",@"Turkish lira",@"Australian dollar",@"Brazilian real",@"Canadian dollar","Chinese yuan",@"Hong Kong dollar",@"Indonesian rupiah",@"Israeli new shekel",@"Indian rupee",@"South Korean won",@"Mexican peso",@"Malaysian ringgit",@"New Zealand dollar",@"Philippine peso",@"Singapore dollar",@"Thai baht",@"South African rand", nil];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [Datarray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting/what is happening when the use the full array?

Comment: @user3338161 Does the app crash?

Comment: No, it just freezes and I'm unable to touch the screen

Comment: check out after @"Canadian dollar","Chinese yuan" looks like you have missed @ over their

Comment: ohh there is the problem, thank you!

Comment: Use new syntax for array initialization: `Datarray2 = @[@"United States Dollar",@"Euro",@"Japanese yen",@"Bulgarian lev",@"Czech koruna",@"Danish krone",@"British pound",@"Hungarian forint"@"Lithuanian litas",@"Polish złoty",@"Romanian leu",@"Swedish krona",@"Swiss franc",@"Norwegian krone",@"Croatian kuna",@"Russian ruble",@"Turkish lira",@"Australian dollar",...];`

Comment: Using the 'new' syntax isn't necessary, or a fix. It's just a compiler shortcut, it'll be compiled into the same thing.

Comment: @AlexBlundell I would argue it is a "fix", since it will give a compile time error. See updated answer.

Comment: Agreed, but the problem was the missing '@', not the way it was initialised as suggested.

Comment: You would be better off putting this list in a plist file instead of hardcoding such an array in your code.

Answer (score 6):

You just missed an `@` sign in one of the strings.

```
Datarray2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"United States Dollar",@"Euro",@"Japanese yen",@"Bulgarian lev",@"Czech koruna",@"Danish krone",@"British pound",@"Hungarian forint"@"Lithuanian litas",@"Polish złoty",@"Romanian leu",@"Swedish krona",@"Swiss franc",@"Norwegian krone",@"Croatian kuna",@"Russian ruble",@"Turkish lira",@"Australian dollar",@"Brazilian real",@"Canadian dollar",@"Chinese yuan",@"Hong Kong dollar",@"Indonesian rupiah",@"Israeli new shekel",@"Indian rupee",@"South Korean won",@"Mexican peso",@"Malaysian ringgit",@"New Zealand dollar",@"Philippine peso",@"Singapore dollar",@"Thai baht",@"South African rand", nil];
```

**Edit:**

Note! Try to use the new ObjC literals. It will give you a compile time error if you do this:

```
id array = @["Chinese"];
```

Answer (score 3):

@"Canadian dollar","Chinese yuan" please change @"Chinese yuan"